# How do I create a Path with a static lifetime from a string with a short lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm currently trying to implement a shell built in Rust for practice, I've managed to implement most features, however, I'm currently trying to make a built-in command which takes `path <arg1> <arg2> ...`, and adds this to my program's path variable. However, I have this setup in that I have a loop which parses the command input and produces a command variable as a `&str` and its arguments as `Vec<&str>` which form my Command struct.

For this built-in command, path, I need to take the arguments and create a new vector of paths and replace the existing path. My current path variable is declared outside of my loop and is a `Vec<&Path>`. I'm currently receiving an error:

```
lifetime mismatch but data from `command` flows into `path` here
```

Which is understandable, but I've tried setting my args to have a `'static` lifetime, but this failed as the `borrowed value does not live long enough`, as I read the line within the loop and replace it and process the string into my command struct. Would appreciate any help!

```rust
let line = stdin.lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap();
let split = line
       .split_whitespace()
       .enumerate()
       .filter(|&(i, _)| i > 0)
       .map(|(_, e)| e);
let args = split.collect::<Vec<&str>>();
```

```rust
// Command Struct
struct Program<'a> {
    command: &'a str,
    args: Vec<&'static str>,
}
// Dispatcher
fn dispatch_command<'a>(command: Program, path: &mut Vec<&Path>) -> Result<(), &'a str>
```

Comment: You should probably just collect into a `Vec<String>` with `.map(|(_, e)| e.to_string())` as the last adapter in the `split` chain. Since you discard `line`, you need to own the individual `args`.

Comment: Side note: the `.enumerate().filter(...).map(...)` chain can be replaced by a `.skip(1)`

Comment: and instead of `stdin.lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap()` you can do `stdin.read_line(&mut input).unwrap()` where `input` is e.g. `let mut input = String::new();`

Comment: @user4815162342 I tried this, however, I still get an error with lifetimes: `borrowed value does not live long enough` when I try to run `path.push(Path::new(&arg));` when arg is a String created from mapping each `&str` to a `String` owned type.

Comment: The `&str`->`String` equivalent for `&Path` is [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html)

Comment: Awesome, thanks @kmdreko, worked like a charm, I saw this earlier but didn't realise you needed to use PathBuf.